# How do I remove the second instance of a substring from a string?

Tags: java, string

To start off, this is a homework problem using java.

"Imagine the user enters a string and a substring. Remove the
second instance of the substring from the string and return the result.
Note that the String API has substring(int, int), charAt(int), and length()
methods you can use."

So far I've tried the following:

```
String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i< string.length(); i++){
          if((i+2)<string.length()&&
            string.charAt(i) == sub.charAt(0)&&
            string.charAt(i) == sub.charAt(1)&&
            string.charAt(i) == sub.charAt(2)){
              i += 2;
            }else{
              result += string.charAt(i);
             }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I was hoping that this would remove the substring from the string at the second instance(i+2).I received an index out of bounds exception for the string = "bird and i".
However in some test cases it doesn't for example the string = "kiaebiariaediaeia", the result I should get is "kiaebiardiaeia." But I didnt.

Comment: The [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) has other methods, too.  Are you allowed to use them?  For this problem, `int indexOf​(String str)` and `int indexOf​(String str, int fromIndex)`, are two methods that might be useful.  If you are not allowed to use them, are you allowed to code your own equivalent methods?

Comment: Your examples are not clear. Which is `"bird and i"`? Is that the long string? Then what's the substring?  Or is it the substring, and what is the long string?  Suggestion: For each example, show the long string, the substring, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It might help to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), with other pages in the Help Center.

Comment: By the way, it would help to show a complete method in your code. We shouldn't have to guess that `string` and `sub` are parameters of the method.

Comment: Please explain how `"kiaebiariaediaeia"` and `""bird and i"` should produce `"kiaebiardiaeia"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `String.indexOf()` to find the start of the first and then second substring.
- You can use `String.substring()` to get the appropriate pieces and concatenate them together.
- `String.length()` will also come in handy.

I recommend you check out the JavaDoc for [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) to understand how the methods work.

Hint:  Remember that when you want to find the second substring, start at the index of the first substring location added to the length of the substring.

It's also a good idea to practice using the methods to see exactly how they work.

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple logical problems, for example - why do you think that `i+2` somehow relates to substring instance? it is single character index two symbols right from the `i`, nothing more

you need to actually search for substring and count how many times you met it, and then you can remove 2nd (or any actually), here is naïve implementation which tries to minimize usage of standard java functions, but show actual algorithm:

```
String result = "";

int instance = 0; // how many instances of sub we already found
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    int endIndex = Math.min(string.length(), i + sub.length()); // we need to calculate substring endIndex to avoid bound exception
    if (string.substring(i, endIndex).equals(sub)) {
        instance++; // we found sub in string, now we want to check is it 2nd one or not
        if (instance == 2) {
            i += sub.length() - 1; // skip 2nd substring
        } else {
            result += string.charAt(i); // keep all other instances
        }
    } else {
        result += string.charAt(i);
    }
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *[String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int))* method, to derive the index.

```java
s.indexOf(ss, s.indexOf(ss) + 1)
```

Alternately, utilize the *[StringBuilder#delete](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,int))* method to adjust the *String*.

```java
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("abc123abc123");
String ss = "abc123";
int i = s.indexOf(ss, s.indexOf(ss) + 1);
s.delete(i, i + ss.length());
```